# count items in an one array, if the number of instances is the same as the length of a different array, return the item, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, id like to return the items from array1 if they appear as much as the length of array2

I understand how to do this in python, but I cant figure out how to do it in javascript

```py
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
arr2 = ['one', 'two']
arr3 = []
```

```py
for i in arr1:
    if arr1.count(i) == len(arr2):
    arr3.append(i)
```

desired result would be ['c']

Can someone please help me write this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**Here idea is :-**

- First use elements of `arr1` as key on `obj`, if key is already there increment it's value, else set it to zero,
- Now take the key's of `obj` and filter if it's value is equal to length of `arr2`

```js
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
let arr2 = ['one', 'two']


let obj = arr1.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let key = inp.toLowerCase()
  op[key] = op[key] || 0
  op[key]++
  return op
},{})

let final = Object.keys(obj).filter(key=>{
  return obj[key] === arr2.length
})

console.log(final)
```

**Note :-** Here i ignored case, if you want both case to be different than you can remove this line

```
  let key = inp.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `reduce()` to create object of whose keys will elements of `arr1` and value will be their count. Then [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) its keys according to given condition.

```js
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
let arr2 = ['one', 'two']

const obj = arr1.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1, ac),{});

let res = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === arr2.length);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops could do that. One for the `for`, and one for the `count`:

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['one', 'two'];
var arr3 = [];

var unique = new Set(arr1);
var len2 = arr2.length;
for(var i of unique){
  var count = 0;
  for(var j of arr1)
    if(j === i)
      count++;
  if(count == len2)
    arr3.push(i);
}

console.log(arr3);
```

Side remark: I think that Python code would result in `['c','c']`, though I have not actually tried.